# The limit of the nth root of a to the n plus b to the n is the maximum of (a,b)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

I've been asked to prove the following from Spivak's *Calculus*
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}=\max(a,b); a,b > 0$$

I understand that this is a proof by cases, and that our cases are $a=b$, $a>b$, and $b>a$. I have done the $a=b$ case, but I am stuck on the $a>b$ and $b>a$ cases.

Some hints would be appreciated-

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $a \leqslant b$

$$b \leqslant (a^n + b^n)^{1/n} \leqslant 2^{1/n} b$$

Answer (score 2):

we assume $a<b$.

Now use the sandwich to obtain:

$b=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{b^n}\leq\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}\leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2b^n}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{2}\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{b^n}=1b$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Factor out the *larger* of the two numbers $a$ and $b$ (remembering that $\root n\of {a^n} = a$).

Answer (score 0):

WLOG let $a>b$.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a\sqrt[n]{1+\left(\dfrac b a\right)^n} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a\left(1+\left(\dfrac b a\right)^n\right)^{1/n} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a + \dfrac a n\left(\dfrac b a\right)^n - \dfrac{a(n-1)}{2n^2} + \cdots \\
&=& \displaystyle a + 0 + 0 + \cdots \\
&=& \displaystyle a \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a >b\ge 0$ then note that $\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n} = a \sqrt[n]{1+({b \over a})^n}$.

Since $\sqrt[n]{1+({b \over a})^n} = e^{{1 \over n} \log (1+({b \over a})^n)}$, we see that $\sqrt[n]{1+({b \over a})^n} \to 1$ from which
the result follows.

Comment: You could also have said: since $h_{n}=1+(\frac{b}{a})^{n}$ is bounded, $\sqrt[n]{h_{n}}=1$.